# How to build a binary tree from down to top?

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am trying to build a tree. I´m begging with the next piece of code:

```
>>> class tree:
    def __init__(self, charge, left=None, right=None):
        self.charge = charge
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

>>> class tree:
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.charge)
```

After writing that I write the next

```
>>> left = tree(2)
```

I write this because its what is supposed to do as the manual  I am using teach.
However I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
left = tree(2)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

How can I build a tree with the code of the beginning from down to top?
By the way my python version is 2.7.2

Comment: why are you coding in pyshell? while defining `class tree` for a second time, you're overwriting the first definition, hence constructor is lost.

Comment: I would also suggest using spaces instead of tabs to indent. You were using a mix of spaces and tabs, which is the worst! It was messing up your formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining a class and then redefining it. Every time you say `class tree:` you create a new class definition, overwriting the previous one. Since the last definition of `tree` doesn't define an `__init__` method, it doesn't take any arguments.

The fact that you are doing this in the interactive interpreter complicates things, because any time you type in a blank line, you end whatever definition you are working on. You might be better off, when it comes to classes, simply editing a text file `mytree.py` and then typing `>>> import mytree`.

Also, if the manual you are using suggests `class foo:` as the way to define classes, and it's about Python 2, then it is a *very old manual*. When using up-to-date versions of Python 2, you should do this:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, ...)
    ...
```

As delnan points out, you don't need to explicitly inherit from `object` in Python 3, so you can leave the parenthesis empty. Indeed, you can omit them entirely; my eye misses the parens when they're absent, but [Dive Into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/iterators.html) doesn't include them at all.

Comment: Well, unless it's Python **3** material, as 3.x thankfully did away with old-style classes.

Comment: @delnan, I thought of that and almost put it in my answer. But doesn't explicitly inheriting from `object` ensure that the code will work the same on 2 and 3? That seems like a good practice to me. But I'm not sure... what do you think?

Comment: You can't and shouldn't try to write code that works in both major versions - there are several differences that cause syntactic incompabilities between what's good code in the two versions. If you absolutely want to support both, you should just write idiomatic 2.x code and run 2to3 (plus perhaps patches for the semantic changes that 2to3 can't handle).

Comment: @delnan, yes, you're right of course. I guess I just like seeing `object` there for some reason :).

Comment: Finally I´ve realized that what I have to do is to use only one time the sentence 'class tree:'.In fact, I was following wrong the manual. In the manual that sentence don´t appear 2 times.